# Identifying record in mysql table based on difference between two specific rows

Tags: mysql, timestamp, compare, difference

I would really appreciate some help with a MySQL query for the following matter.
My table, let's call it "data", contains the following fields: "timestamp" and "temperature". 
Every 30 seconds a new record is being added into it.
My goal is to identify the record (timestamp) which compared to the one added 2 minutes later (4 records later) has a temperature difference of 20 degrees (**or more**)

Ex.

```
...  
19:14:08 99
19:14:38 100
19:15:08 101
19:15:38 105
19:16:08 115
19:16:38 126
19:17:08 150
19:17:38 151
...
```

In this case, the timestamp which I have to find is 19:14:38, because if compared to the one at 19:16:38, we have 126-100 = 26 > 20.

There are some other conditions (not worth mentioning) which have to be met as well, but at least those I can handle myself.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why not consider the timestamp window dressing, and focus on auto inc id's. It will be faster

Comment: This question suggests that you have not spent anytime with sql. Here is a hint, use the greater than symbol, and a limit 1 clause

Comment: I really doubt a simple limit and greater sign will solve my issue. I am looking more into something like a "join" between the same table or a "select in a select".

Comment: what are the inputs and what are the outputs. Devil's in the details

Comment: Maybe something like this, but it's still missing something:

select 
 a.timestamp, a.temperature 
from 
 data a, data b 
where 
 timestampdiff(minute, a.timestamp, b.timestamp) = 2 and 
 (a.temperature-b.temperature) > 20 and 
...

Comment: what are the outputs, 1 row, on up to a ton. It comes down to improving the question. No one can go with this without assumptions. From the Help Center, [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If your timestamps are exactly, you can use a self-join:

```
select t.*
from t join
     t tnext
     on t.timestamp = tnext.timestamp - interval 2 minutes
where tnext.temperature - t.temperature > 20;
```

This is highly dependent on the accuracy of your timestamps, however.

Comment: right, which is why i said "screw the timestamps"  :)

Comment: I have not used auto inc id's because the timestamps are unique (normally i will never have a record with the same one), so I thought having auto inc's would be just a waste. Can ofc always change this.

Comment: Thank you for the "select", I will give it a go.

Comment: The idea is that I need to find this specific moment of the day for specific dates selected from a datepicker by a user in a php/mysql interface.
I was actually seeking help for the select query to see if it is fast enough because on a single page I will have to run it in about 20 tables. (20 different sensors inserting the data in 20 different tables.) Sorry if my question was or still is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe you're on the right track with a join to the same table: something like this should get you started. It's untested air-code and typically I write in oracle sql so pardon any syntax nuances...

```
SELECT
a.TEMPERATURE AS NEW_TEMP
,b.TEMPERATURE AS PRIOR_TEMP
FROM
DATA a
INNER JOIN DATA b ON
   b.TIMESTAMP = a.TIMESTAMP-TO_DATE('02','MM')
   AND ABS(ABS(a.TEMPERATURE) - ABS(b.TEMPERATURE)) > 20
```

Additionally - using a timestamp is probably not as reliable as you might think since there could be variation that you do not want to exist (such as the timestamp may be off by a second ie it is exactly 1:59 seconds prior to the new record. in which case this join would miss it. whereas if you were using an autoincremented ID as suggested above, you could simply replace that first join clause with:

```
b.RECORD_ID = a.RECORD_ID-4
```